# AngularJS filter orderBy in place

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have a list `$scope.calendars` and I want to order by `initial_date`. I'm using `$filter`

```
$filter('orderBy')(this.calendars,'initial_date');
```

My problem is that using `$filter`, angular creates a new list then I lost my reference to my original list. I want to apply filter in place. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Are you ordering only for display or do you need it ordered elsewhere as well?

Comment: @JustinNiessner only for display, but I can remove elements so, I need reorder it again.

Comment: If that's the case, just you `orderBy` on the page (it will bind to the original list and update appropriately): https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy